# How can I track network use per user in my house?

Tags: windows-7, broadband

Our broadband account has a 60 GB monthly cap but we keep exceeding it. I'm trying to get the younger members of the family to understand they can't watch online videos all day but I need to be able to show who's downloading the most.

Most of the internet usage comes from the main PC in the house. Is there a way of recording network usage per user on a Windows 7 PC? Notice the "per user" requirement - there seem to be plenty of tools that will measure internet usage from a single user account.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Yes, each user has their own account. I'm not suggesting we use 60 GB per month *just* on video, but someone is using far more than their fair share - least I think so. This tool would help to prove it!

Comment: Each user logs on to a different account on the Win7 box?

Comment: Hmm.  My back of the envelope calculation suggest that to use 60GB in a month on video, they would have to watch over 2 hours of 1080p youtube video every day (at 2mbps) (most is encoded at far lower resolution).  60GB is a lot to get through if online video is the largest contributor.  Have you done virus/spyware scans to eliminate something unauthorised isn't using the account.  Or checked bitorrent/p2p downloaders aren't present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [Networx](http://www.softperfect.com/products/networx/) and found it could track by user on Windows 7, so that's what I'd recommend to anyone else. As you can see, there's a slight different in network usage after the first week:

[image]

Update: I found there's an option in the settings to synchronise usage data across the network, so although I've got Networx installed on all the PCs in the house I can see the overall usage on any PC:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was in the same boat - going over our 80GB plan after 3 weeks - and with 5 Win7 computers in my house - I installed something called Rokario Bandwidth Monitor on each computer and it has a log of traffic per day for the computer.  I found my 16 yr old was the culprit but he vowed and declared he wasn't up to much so I found another tool called Netbalancer which, even though you only get 30 days free trial, enabled you to see which application was downloading on his machine - it ended up being a virus since he hadn't installed AVG after a recent rebuild he did.

Anyway the tools were useful - I was searching and found too much info and it was hard to find something to do the job.  These may not be the best but they sorted our problem out.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks the same as other tools I've seen - they record traffic from the computer but not via user.

Answer (score -2):

1. I don't know any network-usage monitor (with logging and calculating) for Win7, but I'm not a Win7-guru at all.
2. Just wild idea:

   - Add NAT layer for you connection an any from (any easy Linux-based box with logging capabilities) **OR** cheap PC-box with http-proxy
   - Give each user on "main PC" different LAN-settings
   - Get per-IP logs

*BTW*: for exactly such reasons (easy monitoring and accounting, while our internet-usage can't be abused - real unlimited) I have separate contracts and authentifications for each and every user-host at home

Comment: There's no useful information here.